# Compiler prints HelloWorld whereas Chat GPT says it should only print Hello

Tags: c, unix, gcc, computer-science, gcc-warning

Below is the code I'm compiling:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    printf("Hello%cWorld\n", 0);
}
```

Below is the compiler output:

```
HelloWorld
```

##### Bing Chat-GPT response:start

Below is the same output by Bing chat-gpt in creative mode

```c
Copilot:
The output of printf("Hello%cWorld\n", 0) will be:

Hello
```

The reason is that the %c format specifier expects a single character as an argument, but you provided 0 instead. This is equivalent to the null character '\0', which marks the end of a string in C1. Therefore, the printf function will stop printing the string after encountering the null character, and ignore the rest of the characters.

To print the whole string as it is, you need to use the %s format specifier, which expects a string as an argument. For example:

```c
printf("Hello%sWorld\n", "\0");

This will print:

Hello\0World
```

Alternatively, you can escape the backslash character with another backslash, like this:

```c
printf("Hello\\0World\n");

This will also print:

Hello\0World
```

You:
but when I compiled the above code it gave me output as HelloWorld

Copilot:
That is strange. The code you posted should give a warning and print only Hello. Are you sure you compiled the same code? Maybe you have a different version of the compiler or the standard library that handles the null character differently. Can you show me the exact command you used to compile and run the code?

You:
I have used gcc main.c -o app to compile

Copilot:
I see. And how did you run the app? Did you use any command-line arguments or input redirection?

You:
I ran the app using ./app command I did not use any command-line arguments or input redirection

Copilot:
I see. Well, I’m not sure why you got a different output than expected. According to the C standard, the behavior of printf with a null character argument is undefined1. This means that different compilers or platforms may handle it differently, and there is no guarantee of consistency or correctness. Maybe your compiler or platform has some special treatment for the null character, or maybe you encountered some memory corruption or other bug.

To avoid this kind of problem, I suggest you always use valid arguments for the printf function, and follow the rules of the format specifiers. You can find more information about the printf function and its format specifiers in this article2.

I hope this helps. If you have any other questions, feel free to ask me.

1: warning: format string contains ‘\0’ within the string body [-Wformat] 2: printf in C - GeeksforGeeks

##### Bing Chat-GPT response:end

Please note GCC version:

```
coder@069e69391cf2:~/project/Rough/programs/3$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.2.1 20191008 (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2)
```

- I wanted to learn, in `printf("Hello%cWorld\n", 0)` here %c expects matching int argument.
- Hence I gave 0, this turns out to be NULL with respect to ASCII characters.

I need to know why there are two different outputs i.e. compiler prints `HelloWorld` & chat-gpt
says only `Hello` should be printed.

Please help to explain this behavior ?

Thanks.

Comment: ChatGPT is not a compiler, nor a programmer - so why do you care what it "thinks"?

Comment: The information provided by ChatGPT is completely WRONG.  Unfortunately that's the case far too often.

Comment: Well, you just found out how useful ChatGPT really is.  If it screws this up, what can't it screw up?  And how would you know?

Comment: Links to this are on the right on every page: [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/5382650)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is posting a chatGPT answer and wants to know why it doesn't match the code.

Comment: Why would you ask various chat bot lie generators about programming? It only cares to produce an answer it thinks you want to hear - it has no concepts of facts or correctness.

Comment: OTOH the output of this is quite surprising... https://godbolt.org/z/sW1MnMaE5

Comment: @Jabberwocky Are you surprised that godbolt doesn't print a box character or something when it outputs 0?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Why would that be surprising? Maybe we do want to generate a null terminated string with some goo appended to it? You can hide secret love letters behind the null terminator :)

Comment: @Anton The first parameter of the function printf is declared as having the type const char *. So the string in this call printf("Hello%cWorld\n", 0); is not being changed. Its characters are sent to the standard output stream and when a format specifier is encountered then it is skipped and instead of it the corresponding argument is sent to the output.

Comment: The compiler is correct. (and why wouldn't it be). Also note how the text generator first tells you that `\0` marks the end of a string, but then contradicts itself and claims that it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This is entirely explained by the fact that ChatGPT is wrong and is not a source of factual information. ChatGPT tells you this in its [terms of use](https://openai.com/policies/terms-of-use):

> Output may not always be accurate. You should not rely on Output from our Services as a sole source of truth or factual information, or as a substitute for professional advice.

and:

> YOU ACCEPT AND AGREE THAT … YOU WILL NOT RELY ON OUTPUT AS A SOLE SOURCE OF TRUTH OR FACTUAL INFORMATION, OR AS A SUBSTITUTE FOR PROFESSIONAL ADVICE.

Going further, `printf("Hello%cWorld\n", 0);` tells `printf` to print “Hello”, then to print the character with code 0, then to print “World” and a new-line character. The 0 character is sent to the terminal and typically results in no display, so the “W” will appear immediately after the “o”.

Answer (score 2):

When `printf` parses `"Hello%cWorld\n"` and sees `%c`, it doesn't grab the supplied argument, `0`, inserts it instead of `%c` and then notices, "oh, the string ends here". It continues to parse until the *format* string hits a `\0`.

The resulting output will therefore be `Hello\0World\n` (where `\0` is the `0` you gave as an argument and `\n` is line feed - new line).

Answer (score 1):

Your Bing chat-gpt's output is wrong.

The `%c` format specifier of `printf` takes an `int` argument (`char` is automatically promoted to `int` in variable-length argument), converts the value to `unsigned char`, and emit the result as a byte.

Therefore, (assuming that ASCII is used) the code

```c
printf("Hello%cWorld\n", 0);
```

will emit bytes:

```
48 65 6c 6c 6f 00 57 6f 72 6c 64 0a
```

Your viewer application may ignore the NUL byte `00` and display this sequence of bytes as `HelloWorld`.

The code

```c
printf("Hello%sWorld\n", "\0");
```

will emit bytes without NUL byte:

```
48 65 6c 6c 6f 57 6f 72 6c 64 0a
```

because the `%s` format specifier takes a (pointer to) **string** as the argument and strings in C are terminated by a NULL character `\0`. Therefore, what is passed here is a pointer to 2-byte array `00 00` and this is interpreted as 0-character string (the first byte is the terminator).

The code

```c
printf("Hello\\0World\n");
```

will emit bytes:

```
48 65 6c 6c 6f 5c 30 57 6f 72 6c 64 0a
```

Because `\\` is an escape sequence that means a character `\`, and `0` after `\\` is simply a character `0` without any special meanings.